# type resources does not exist in namespace error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, namespaces, resources

Got another problem. I had almost finished my project but felt like I had to change the namespace of the project. 
But instead of using refactor --> rename , I selected my namespace, edit --> find and replace and replaced my whole solution with a different namespace (so everywhere in the solution where for example the namespace or text "name1" exists, is now changed into "name2").

But now I get around 16 errors all saying the same thing: "The type or namespace "resources" does not exist in namespace name1".

```
     this.centerPanel.BackgroundImage = global::login_DragDrop.Properties.Resources.oeftest;
```

So for example in this line of code (mainly in the designer.cs) resources is colored red?

Any hints on how to fix this?

Comment: Is the default namespace in your project properties also changed accordingly? After you fixed that goto your resource file (under Properties), right-click and choose Run Custom Tool

Comment: Thanks guy , very helpfull , did the trick :)

Answer (score 55):

You need to run the code generation on the resource file to get the correct namespace there as well.

Follow these steps:

- Open the project properties (right click > properties)

  - click the Application section
  - Enter your prefered Default namespace
  - Close and save your properties
- navigate in the solution explorer to your Resouces.resx file (under Properties)

  - Right-click the Resources.resx file
  - Choose 'Run Custom Tool' (or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)

This runs the code generation for the resource files again. The generated code makes that you have strongly typed access to the values in your resource strings.

Comment: Using VS2013.  I found that I had to not only update the namespace for the project's Application default namespace, but also the namespace for the .resx File Properties: Custom Tool Namespace.  These two places are assumed to be separate from the code development and so they are not found by a Global Find and Replace.

Comment: @shipr Thanks for reporting that. I don't have that Custom Tool set in VS2010 but I'll check VS2013 and edit my answer tonight.

Answer (score 7):

Run Custom Tool did not work for me.
But I found if I added a resource the problem fixed itself.

Follow these steps:

- Open the project properties (right click > properties)
- Click the Resources section
- In the Add Resource drop down select Add Existing File
- Select any resource file. (I picked an existing image file)

  - **At this point my errors disappeared.**
- Select the resource you just added
- Click Remove Resource (to clean up)
- Close and save your properties

Late (very) response I know but there you go.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the `Resource.Designer.cs` file was somehow excluded from project... Clicked on show hidden files (show all files), included it in project with a right-click and it was fixed. Phew..

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have tried to add another resource file with the same name as an already existing resource. 
To fix this simply delete the corresponding line in the Resources.resx file, for example you will see two lines that have the same "Data name" :

```
  <data name="button" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\button.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the answers worked in my case, I decided to post by own answer.

Here is what I did:

- Create class with same name (X) in the exact same namespace (Y).
- "*The namespace 'Y' already contains a definition for 'X'.*" error appears.
- Delete class X.

After deleting the class, my resource with name X remained visible in the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I also renamed my project namespace using "find and replace" and had the same problem.  The application fix suggested by @rene was one fix (thanks) but I discovered that "settings.settings" had the old namespace name.  With VS2019 I did not see any way to find the wrong name and I resorted to "find" to hunt down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error code does not necessarily have to do anything with changing namespace. It simply means that the file "Resources.Designer.cs" does not exist. As this file is automatically generated when the code is compiled, you need to look at the file "Resources.resx" to find out what went wrong.

1. You renamed a resource file.
2. You accidentally deleted a resource file.
3. ???

Either way you may need to open Resources.resx in Solution Explorer under "Properties". There you will see a bunch of icons which represent your resources (in my case a bunch of .png files). Find the icons which are greyed out and either delete them or re-generate them (restore them in the operating system).