# In-Design Mode error - "Resource has no property named 'myResource'"

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, designer

We get a really weird scenario where we have resources in a projet marked as Embedded.

In Visual Studio environment, while developping, the return error is :

> The type 'OurProject.My.Resources.Resources' has no property named
> 'tlSearch_Image'

But I promise you it exists! We see it when going in project's properties. And any other resource are not failing so they are ok, exept this one! Even Inteliscence allow us to refers to it without any compilation error.

Here are what we tried :

- Clear Solution / Rebuild = FAILED
- Deleting everything we can in project's folder in relation with DEBUG (In OBJ and BIN) = FAILED
- Restarting our computer (Microsoft, YAY!!) = FAILED
- Delete everything, and get everything back from our SVN Trunk = FAILED
- Remove image from designer, and add it back = FAILED
- Trying to remove my resrouce from project's Resources, and add it back... work for a while (like few minutes) and then = FAILED
- Dancing all around computer with a party hat = FAILED

And to add to the complexity, it only fails on my computer... not on any other computers of our team and worked pretty well yesterday. All this, even if no "major" changes were made since then. But anyway, all our team are at the same SVN version... and I'm the only one who fails.

Anyone has already experienced this before because it's really anoying as I can't see my form while developping... but I can start debugging (<kbd>F5</kbd>) and it does not fail. Please note that is not a self reference problem as we saw in other post from google search results.

Our environment : Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2008 .NET Framework 3.5

### EDIT

Something we also tried was to removing resource, save it as another name (such as `tlSearch` instead of `tlSearch_Image`) and it WORKED... for a day or so. Then, it starts crashing my designer once again. And still only for me! We are now wondering if it is not a Graphical issues or something! Please help!

### EDIT #2

Ok, now, I'm not alone... Two other colleague are experiencing same error...

Here's a printscreen of what I got:
[image]

Comment: Try open your form designer (I think in vb it is FormName.designer.vb), to find why you get error.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this but there is no compilation error... It is more like if it was Visual Studio itself fails... like if it fails loading my image for an unknown reason. The intellisense allows me to specify it, as it is supposed to because indeed, it exists

Comment: Does your image filename contains some spesial characters like "."?

Comment: No... in fact, it does not exists physically. It is embedded in our Resource File. So, there is no real filname. There only a `ResourceName` and in our case, this is `tlSearch_Image`

Comment: When you opend the `.designer.vb` file, try remove `tlSearch_Image` and type it again.

Comment: Also tried... still fails.

Comment: Try comment the line that contains `tlSearch_Image`

Comment: @Masoud: I really tried every manipulations directly in link with image such as remove, replace, rename, etc and it still fails. This kindly more about Visual Studio and something like a memory issues or something. We are hardly tring to make it work for about 3 hours so these kind of manipulation has already been executed...

Comment: Next step... we'll try to reformat my computer XD! Wow... One day of non productivity because of that...

Answer (score 0):

just comment the current cusror when you click on error 
where image name mention just comment that row and then come to form design that error will disappear do same with all your errors

Comment: Can you clarify your answer? For example step by step sections with screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706839/type-resources-does-not-exist-in-namespace-error/23710788#23710788) answer might help you.

- Right-click on project->Properties->Resources.rsx
- Select Run Custom Tools
- Clean The Solution
- Rebuild The project

If its not worked restart visual studio and check