# Get name of called field

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on pretty large and very old application.
So after some sort of refactoring I do have TONS of calls to

```
Resources.differentNames
```

All these calls are not resolved (means, I'll have to create such a class). Over that, I find it unreasonable to create a field for each of such calls.

The goal: is to create a Resources class which would accept a call to

```
Resources.WHATEVER
```

and I need to be able in Resources to get such a WHATEVER word to make some sort of swith at that point to return specific value I need.

The question is: How to do it? (if it's possible)

Comment: in C#6, `nameof(MyField);` is there to get the name of the called field.

Comment: Have a look at `ExpandoObject` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Are you sure that due to your refactoring you only need to regenerate the resource files: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23710788/578411

Comment: Guys, great thanks for your help.

Rahu, I do not need to know the name of the field I'm going to call. I do need to access the field from the inside of Resources class.

Dmitry, thanks, but I need to dynamically get the name of any possibly called field of the Resources class. 

rene, namespaces are out of current topic. Thanks though.