# Designer fails to recognise an existing resource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

The designer was working until I deleted an image resource (from Resources folder under solution explorer,note that the image was not used anywhere), the designer stopped working and displayed the following:

[image]

notice that the unrecognised property exists, and I checked it in the generated designer code and it works fine, also the application builds and runs normally, but I can't get to the designer view in any way!

I tried to remove them and adding all resources again with no success.

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636840/designer-fails-my-resources-resources-has-no-property-named) but in his case it seems like resources were missing, but I'am sure that mine are in the right place.

Can anybody help me figure out what is happening?

Comment: Can you check if the second bullet mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23710788/578411) will resolve your issue?

Comment: He have errors in his designer code, but I don't have any errors there, the images resolves normally when accessed through code (Properties.Resources....) only designer view fails to find them!